# Как запомнить url для каждого поситителя на своем сайте?

Tags: javascript, cookie, url

Появилась техническая необходимость запоминать `url`, на котором клиент остановился при просмотре сайта и подмены стандартного `url` на сохраненный при повторном посещении, но в рамках одного сайта.
Изучив вопрос пришел к выводу, что можно реализовать или через сессию или через `cookie`. С сессией не понятно т.к. после закрытия браузера работать с клиентом не получится, а у `cookie` есть маленький срок жизни. 
Кто-то сталкивался с подобной задачей?

Comment: У `cookie` маленький срок жизни? На какое максимальное время пытались поставить куку?

Answer (score 1):

Есть [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), в нём нет времени жизни.